# Why is grid-auto-columns having no effect?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I was exploring [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) and this is something I do not understand. I have used `grid-auto-columns` with `grid-template-columns` but it does not affect anything.

I have tried to set various values in `grid-auto-columns` but it does not affect anything.

Why not?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-columns: 50px;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: 2px solid rgb(233, 171, 88);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(233, 171, 88, .5);
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: solution found: [If a grid item is positioned into a column that is not explicitly sized by grid-template-columns, implicit grid tracks are created to hold it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

The reason `grid-auto-columns` is having no effect is the absence of columns in the *implicit* grid.

---

### Explanation

In CSS Grid Layout, there are two types of grids: *explicit* and *implicit*.

An **explicit grid** is the grid that you explicitly define. You create an explicit grid when you use the following properties:

- `grid-template-rows`
- `grid-template-columns`
- `grid-template-areas`
- `grid` (which is the shorthand for the three properties above, [among others](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#grid-shorthand))

However, you are not required to keep grid items in the explicit grid. You can essentially place items and create grid areas anywhere you want, even outside the explicit grid. That's where the implicit grid comes in.

The **implicit grid** is created by rows and columns that are automatically generated to accommodate grid items that are positioned outside of the explicit grid.

While `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` size explicit tracks, `grid-auto-columns` and `grid-auto-rows` size implicit tracks.

Looking at your code, there are two columns and three rows in the explicit grid.

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-columns: 50px;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

The three explicit rows will take an equal distribution of the free space (`1fr`). Any additional rows will have a height of 200px.

The two explicit columns will take an equal distribution of the free space. Any additional columns will have a width of 50px.

*But in your code there are no columns outside the explicit grid; there are only two columns. So `grid-auto-columns` has no effect.*

Here's how the spec defines these grid types:

> [**7.1. The Explicit
>   Grid**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grids)
>
> The three properties `grid-template-rows`, `grid-template-columns`,
>   and `grid-template-areas` together define the explicit grid of a grid
>   container.
>
> The `grid` property is a shorthand that can be used to set all three
>   at the same time.
>
> The final grid may end up larger due to grid items placed outside the
>   explicit grid; in this case implicit tracks will be created, these
>   implicit tracks will be sized by the `grid-auto-rows` and
>   `grid-auto-columns` properties.
>
> ---
>
> [**7.5. The Implicit
>   Grid**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#implicit-grids)
>
> The `grid-template-rows`, `grid-template-columns`, and
>   `grid-template-areas` properties define a fixed number of tracks that
>   form the explicit grid.
>
> When grid items are positioned outside of these bounds, the grid
>   container generates implicit grid tracks by adding implicit grid lines
>   to the grid.
>
> These lines together with the explicit grid form the implicit grid.
>
> The `grid-auto-rows` and `grid-auto-columns` properties size these
>   implicit grid tracks.

Comment: as per MDN documentation [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) property is the shorthand of all `grid-*` properties not only these 3.`grid-template-rows`, `grid-template-columns`, and  `grid-template-areas`

Comment: @pro.mean, thanks for the clarification. To be precise, it's a shorthand for many `grid-*` properties, but not all of them. I updated the answer.